# Develop Android app to transfer file from one device to another over BLE

Tags: android

**I want to develop android app  by which i can send files over Bluetooth Low Energy from one device to another .**

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you have tried (by showing a [mcve]) and explain what problems you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified problem You are facing. If its communication over bt i recommend to use one of libraries. No need to reinventing a wheel.

I was using this one:
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/690

And this worked fine for me but You can use any other.
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/134?sort=created